# Get latest record with max and group by

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am working on a php application and need to retrieve the latest record from a mysql table. Below is the table design and sample data.

So the criteria is:

sort by present DESC,
then start_date DESC

[image: Database table]

Expected Output

[image: Expected output]

I am thinking as below, is there any better solutions on this?

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `experience` r 
  JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(start_date) as date, 
               resume_id 
          FROM `experience` 
         WHERE present = 1 
         group by resume_id
        )r2 ON r.resume_id = r2.resume_id 
           AND r.present = 1 
           AND r.start_date = r2.date  
UNION
SELECT * 
  FROM `experience` r 
  JOIN (
        SELECT MAX(start_date) as date, 
               resume_id 
          FROM `experience` 
         WHERE present = 0 
         group by resume_id
       ) r2 ON r.resume_id = r2.resume_id 
           AND r.present = 0 
           AND r.start_date = r2.date  
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                     FROM `experience` 
                    WHERE present = 1 
                      AND r.resume_id = resume_id
                  )

// took around 11-20 seconds to process above query on total 499,000 records
```

Explain query

[image: Explain Query]

UPDATE:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bc5a12/1

```
CREATE TABLE `experience`(
       `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
       `resume_id` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
       `company_name` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
       `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
       `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
       `present` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL
       ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `experience`(
       `id`, 
       `resume_id`,  
       `company_name`, 
       `start_date`, 
       `end_date`, 
       `present`) 
 VALUES
(1, '1', 'abc', '2009-01-01', '2009-12-31', '0'),
(2, '1', 'def', '2010-01-01', '2012-12-31', '0'),
(3, '1', 'ghi', '2013-01-01', '0000-00-00', '1'),
(4, '2', 'abc', '2009-01-01', '2009-12-31', '0'),
(5, '2', 'def', '2010-01-01', '2012-12-31', '0'),
(6, '2', 'ghi', '2013-01-01', '2016-01-01', '0'),
(7, '3', 'abc', '2009-01-01', '2009-12-31', '0'),
(8, '3', 'def', '2017-01-01', '0000-00-00', '1'),
(9, '3', 'ghi', '2010-01-01', '0000-00-00', '1');

ALTER TABLE `experience`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

Comment: Huh?  I don't see how to get the expected output without a `WHERE` clause.  Even then, I see no way for _that_ `ORDER BY` to come even close to _that_ expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a joke (but must work nevertheless):

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM experience t1
JOIN ( SELECT resume_id, 
              MAX(start_date + INTERVAL 1000 * present YEAR) start_date
       FROM experience t2
       GROUP BY resume_id ) t3 USING (resume_id)
WHERE t1.start_date + INTERVAL 1000 * t1.present YEAR = t3.start_date
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a6b201fd3b3cdfefeb1adb78c0f417e4)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127303/discussion-between-cww-and-akina).